# Firebase emulators, on startup, creates multiple "firebase-export..." folders outside of my --import path at the root of my project

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

In my `package.json` I have the following `dev` script, that runs `start:emulators`. The script goes to the root of my project and then runs `emulators:start`, which sets the import path to `./saved-data`.

```
"start:emulators": "cd ~/AndroidStudioProjects/order_fulfillment && firebase emulators:start --import=./saved-data --export-on-exit",
"dev": "concurrently --kill-others \"npm run start:emulators\" \"npm run ts:watch\"",
```

This work just fine, and my data always successfully imports and exports to the `saved-data` directory at the root of my project. However, this process also creates artifacts that I have to constantly delete from the root of my project. Anyone know why? It is more annoying than anything else. I just have to keep clearing them from time to time. They seem to have no bearing on exported data in the `saved-data` directory.

[image]

Firebase [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure) state "--export-on-exit= Optional...The export directory can be specified with this flag: firebase emulators:start --export-on-exit=./saved-data. If --import is used, the export path defaults to the same; for example: firebase emulators:start --import=./data-path --export-on-exit." I don't see anything in the docs about these artifact firebase-export... folders purpose at the root.

Comment: Looks like a bug - please file an issue here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues

Comment: Is this caused only by the storage emulator? I have found exactly this to be the case. No solution as yet

Comment: @zelf did you manage to find a solution for this ?

Comment: @thezohaan negative. In some release the issue was resolved. I'm no longer seeing these export files pile up. However, I'm no longer using the concurrently package to start up emulators. Not sure if that is part of the fix either.

Comment: @zelf thanks, indeed i was using run-p to start and without that it seems to work fine.

Answer (score -2):

remove the "--export-on-exit" and u won't have your data duplicated,
this line will always create a new set of data, remove it and u won't have new folder which will be created

Comment: If you don't have export on exit then data will not be saved. This was not the issue.